# C# Azure Blob Client Download Large blob is slow

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

We are using the below code to download Azure blobs in C# .NET 4.8 using the Azure Blob client, latest version.

For some regions, we are seeing download speeds in C# of as slow as 7 Mbps.  However, on the same box using Azure Storage Explorer, we are able to get 300 Mbps.  The Azure Blob is a standard premium LRS blob.

Is there something about this code, or how we are using it, that could be causing the issue?  Thanks in advance.  Why would Azure Storage Explorer on the same box be >10X faster than C# on that same box?

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(ConnectionString);

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(ContainerName);

BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(BlobPath);

using (BlobDownloadInfo download = blobClient.DownloadAsync().Result)
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(download.Content))
    {
        fileData = reader.ReadBytes(BytesToRead);
    }

}
```

Comment: How large is "large" in your example?

Answer (score 2):

IMO, your code is OK. However, it is expected that speeds are not equal on different azure centers worldwide, and the geographical location/distance to your location also matters.

Check this azure website tests blob storage service speed https://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/ to give you an idea.

There is also another site to check latency https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Latency

I will add this might give more info:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/663188/azure-files-high-latency-low-iops-when-writing-to.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/829113/sometimes-download-from-azure-blob-storage-is-very.html

Comment: Is there a way to improve this code, or to enable it to use multiple threads to download (similar to what Azure Storage Explorer does)?  Why would Azure Storage Explorer on the same box be >10X faster than C# on that same box?

Comment: I do not think multiple threads will help in this case. The only thing I can think of is that I am not sure how Azure Storage Explorer works behind the scenes but maybe it is using a kind of cache, and therefore if feels faster. I need to investigate that.